# Error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-http-interceptors

I want to intercept http response, especially if any errors like 401. So I am using catch block after toPromise. But I am getting error below.

Error : Type 'void | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse | HttpUserEvent' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent'.

Here is my interceptor code. Can you tell what is wrong in code and give solution. Thanks

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpHeaders
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { TokenService } from '../services/token.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { observable, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/internal-compatibility';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private tokenService: TokenService,
        private authService: AuthService) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return fromPromise(this.handleAccess(request, next));
    }

    private async handleAccess(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const token = await this.tokenService.getToken();
        const lang = localStorage.getItem('pref_lang');
        
        let changedRequest = request;
       
        const headerSettings: { [name: string]: string | string[]; } = {};

        for (const key of request.headers.keys()) {
            headerSettings[key] = request.headers.getAll(key);
        }
        if (token) {
            headerSettings['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        }
        
        headerSettings['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        headerSettings['Accept-Language'] = lang;

        const newHeader = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings);
        changedRequest = request.clone({
            headers: newHeader
        });
        return next.handle(changedRequest).toPromise().catch(error => {
            console.log('HttpErrorResponse error', error);
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                console.log('HttpErrorResponse error status code', error.status);
                switch ((<HttpErrorResponse>error).status) {
                    case 401:
                        return this.handle401Error(request, next);
                }
            } else {
                console.log('something went wrong error', error);
            }
        });
    }

    handle401Error(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    console.log('handle401Error called...');
    if (!this.isRefreshingToken) {
        this.isRefreshingToken = true;
        let cachedRequest = req;
        this.authService.getFreshAccessToken().then((res) => {
            next.handle(cachedRequest).toPromise();
        }).catch(error => {
             this.authService.logout();
        }).finally(() => {
            cachedRequest = null;
            this.isRefreshingToken = false;
        });
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put some comments inside:

```
--8<---
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                console.log('HttpErrorResponse error status code', error.status);
                switch ((<HttpErrorResponse>error).status) {
                    case 401:
                        return this.handle401Error(request, next);
                    // here, you're missing the default-case. HttpErrorResponses other than status 401 are completely ignored and the return-type will be void, as the else-statement below is never reached
                }
            } else {
                // you should return something here, as not returning anything at all is the same as returning void
                console.log('something went wrong error', error);
            }
            // the default could be to just rethrow the error to let the caller handle it. This should also remove the compiler error
            throw error;
--8<---
```

Comment: After throw error statement, error gone. But here my doubt is, in handle401Error(request, next) method, I am refreshing token from server and on success have try same request again. So if I throw error will disturb that flow?

Comment: Nope, it won't, because the last return statement is never reached in case you return the retry-logic based Promise in the case 401-statement!

Comment: Somehow request is not getting re-try. Could you please tell me what is wrong and correct way to doing this.

Comment: code is updated with handle 401 method. Can you please tell me what's is wrong with code. Thanks